# SQL error retrieving data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep running this code and get the same error no matter what I change.

```
require('common.php');
$charname = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$query = "SELECT group, guild, username, class, level 
      FROM DD_users 
      WHERE username = '".$charname."'";
try
{
// These two statements run the query against your database table.
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
// Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
// It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

//print_r($rows);
$group = $rows['0']['adminaccess'];
$guild = $rows['0']['guild'];
$username = $rows['0']['username'];
$class = $rows['0']['class'];
$level = $rows['0']['level'];
```

It returns this error
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, guild, username, class, level FROM DD_users ' at line 1`
And apparently I need more text to be able to edit this...

Comment: If you intend on constructing queries like this then don't waste resources on using prepared statements and just go with `$db->query()`. Not to mention that by using prepared statements with placeholders you are actually preventing some serious security issues which you might face if you try to construct query strings by yourself.

Comment: I honestly got this from a login guide. Are you saying with the code I have now that is more secure then just doing `$db->query()`? If so, then I think it would be better to use a little bit of resources then drop security. I mean, its only going to be a very small site anyways with computer illiterate people so there is little chance someone would try to hack it anyways.

Comment: No its not because you are using `prepare()` yet you make no use of what its actually supposed to be used for. If you have simple queries which don't require using external parameters such as `$charname` you can use query() however if you need to supply parameters you should use parameter binding through `bindParam()` or  directly by supplying the parameters as an array to `execute()`. Long story short somebody already answered the question while providing an example about what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

`$query = "SELECT group, guild, username, class, level 
          FROM DD_users 
          WHERE username = '".$charname."'";`

note the additional quotes `'`. They are required if you query for a string.

also: `group` might be a reserved keyword. you need to escape that with `-style quotes or .brackets `[`. try which works

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I will select it answered when I can and would upvote if i could.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot `'` character:

```
$query = "SELECT group, guild, username, class, level 
          FROM DD_users 
          WHERE username = '".$charname."'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Watch that the group keyword is reserved, try enclosing it in backticks `

Comment: I changed the column name. I didn't know there were reserved words. Some of them make sense too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would save you the hassles with the single quotes--but more importantly it would also guard you against a SQL injection attack. You *NEVER* want to take input and push it straight into a SQL query string.  Terrible things can happen.

Note the `?` mark in the query string, and the passing of `$charname` value to substitute for the `?` via the `execute(array($charname))` call.  Doing things this way will let the underlying library code safely quote $charname into the query.

```
require('common.php');
$charname = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$query = "SELECT `group`, guild, username, class, level 
          FROM DD_users 
          WHERE username = ?";
try
{
    // These two statements run the query against your database table.
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($charname));
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

print_r($rows);
```

Comment: I updated my first post to what I have now. When I use your code, I get the same error as before.

Comment: `group` is a sql keyword.  I added backticks to quote it as an identifier.  Try my updated code!  Hope this works for you.  Without those backquotes, you'll get the syntax error.

Comment: That and I forgot to change that in the script. All is good. Thanks for the pointer.